# Does anyone know how to enter list of website resources and output an xml doc for Flash use

Tags: xml, flash, parsing

I've got to construct a basic xml file listing website assets (pictures and text strings) that a flash photo gallery references.

I'm using a Mac and OpenOffice. I've got Dreamweaver, dashcode, and a couple of open source IDE's. I'm not a programmer, so scripting gets a little difficult.

I'm hand typing the file right now, but the task is very slow because of the number and order of the "fields" and values for each record in the xml.

Is it possible to set up a spreadsheet of the data and then parse an xml file from that? I've got to follow this format for each record:

```
<photo imageurl="url" linklabel="text"linkurl="url" showFlipButton="true"><title>text</title><description>text</description></photo>
```

Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MSExcel I would use the Concatenate() function to manually build out the XML for each row, as a quick and dirty solution.  You should be able to do this with OpenOffice as well.

Comment: Concatenate worked out. The one trick was to create extra columns holding the field names, quotes, and values that had to be inserted in between the data. Also, OpenOffice wanted to use curly quotes for everything, so I had to turn that off. Thanks a lot, Mitchell. I've got a lot of this drudge work to do.

Comment: Yes, the extra columns helps....

If this did help, don't forget to select it as the answer...